# Two cell group alignment left

Tags: html, css

I actually tried everything and can't find CSS solution.

I have simple table of rows, with two columns.
The table has FIXED width of 400px.
I have left column aligned right, and right column aligned left.
So it looks like this:

```
       Table header
===============================
     Firstname: John
      Lastname: Smith
           Age: 49
===============================
```

Since the table is wider than data,
data shown looks not good.

What I want to achieve is same result, but both cells now
aligned left (no padding in front)

```
       Table header
===============================
Firstname: John
 Lastname: Smith
      Age: 49
===============================
```

I could do this simple with defining cell's width, but
I don't know the data in advance.

So I need to remove td:first-child padding spaces, but
don't know how.

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `width: 1px; white-space: nowrap;` in `td:first-child` to remove padding

check out my **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ARQLL/)**

Answer (score 1):

in your css, at the bottom of the file write

```
td:first-child {
    padding: 0;   /* you could also try padding: 0 !important;
}
```

and see if that works